# What is the PowerShell equivalent for a Windows Command Processor FOR loop searching for files matching a pattern and running an EXE with each file?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have this Windows command line in a batch file:

```
for %%f in (*fla) do fla2comp.exe -d "%%f"
```

How does the command line look in PowerShell syntax?

`fla2comp.exe` is in the directory of the batch file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve all files in the current folder matching the wildcard name `*fla`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *fla
```

To loop through each file, pipe the output to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *fla |ForEach-Object { <# $_ will contain a reference to each file here #>}
```

Then pass the `FullName` property (it'll contain the rooted file path) of each file object to `fla2comp.exe`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *fla |ForEach-Object {
    fla2comp.exe -d $_.FullName
}
```